# How to create VarArgs in java bean and Jackson Json?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, jackson

I am receiving a json from my client side as

```
{
"name":"name",
"type":"type",
"value": "one"
}
```

or

```
{
"name":"name",
"type":"type",
"value": [
"one",
"two"
]
}
```

I want to create a JAVA object which should accept both the payload.

I worked on varargs in Java buut i never tried varargs in Java model.
Trying to create a java bean like this,

```
private String name;
private String type;
private String... value;
```

But getting compilation error as "Unexpected Token".

Then changed my POJO to like this,

```
private String name;
private String type;
private String[] value;
```

But Jackson throwing an exception **Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token**

Even i am ready to change my Java bean as per my json structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem appears to be that you want a String[] to correspond to both a single String value ans an array of Strings. If only I knew Jackson...

Comment: Did you try to change your pojo to `private List<String> value` ?

Comment: @ToddSewell...Indeed. But is it possible to create Varargs in Java Bean instead of String[]?

Comment: @ErickMaia...I don't want that attribute to be list string...ex)If i am sending the POJO as a response it will change the structure ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try it?

```
class Data {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String[] value;

    //gettes and setters
}


public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper =
                new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        String json1 = "{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"type\",\"value\":\"one\"}";
        String json2 = "{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"type\",\"value\":[\"one\",\"two\"]}";

        Data data1 = mapper.readValue(json1, Data.class);
        Data data2 = mapper.readValue(json2, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data1);
        System.out.println(data2);
    }
}
```

The property DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY must help.